# Графика в java ,android. Отдельный Bimap под каждую копию изображения?

Tags: java, android, canvas

Допустим есть изображение шарика , я хочу вывести на экран 10 шариков, каждый имеет свою координату. Под каждое изображение шарика должен выделяться отдельный Bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете сделать как 10 отдельных bitmap можно нарисовать в на canvas и сделать как одну bitmap

Comment: но зачем тогда мне создавать 10 отдельных битмапов , если  я могу все через один сделать ? наверно незачем. А вот если бы я хотел использовать различные изображения , то под каждое изображение один битмап, я прав ? И еще скажите битмап это способ кодировки растрового изображения и когда я битмапу присваиваю из ресурсов изображение , он его перекодирует под свой формат и хранит результат кодировки, который я сколько угодно раз и использую. Верно мыслю ?

Comment: Если 10 отдельных изображений, то 10 bitmap. Да, Вы верно мыслите/ вот на вики https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap про битмап. Все просто расписано